# Work to pump from Hemispherical Tank Calc 2

Tags: calculus, integration

I keep having trouble with [this](https://www.rit.edu/studentaffairs/asc/sites/rit.edu.studentaffairs.asc/files/docs/services/resources/handouts/C9_WorkbyIntegration_BP_9_22_14.pdf) problem I found online and I do not know where my reasoning went wrong.  The problem states,

> Find the work done by pumping out molasses from a hemispherical tank with a radius of 4 feet when the initial depth of the molasses is at 2 feet. Molasses weighs 100 ${lb}\over{ft^3}$.

For a reference frame, I used $x^2+(y-4)^2=16$

From that, I determined $$\int_0^2 100(\pi r^2)(4-y)dy$$

Since $r=x$ for my reference frame, I solved for $x^2$, giving me $$x^2=16-(y-4)^2$$  $$x^2=8y-y^2$$
Putting that back into the integral, I got
$$\int_0^2 100\pi(8y-y^2)(4-y)dy$$
Evaluating this gives me $11309.7 ft \cdot lb$

The website's correct answer is $2094.4 ft \cdot lb$, where did I go wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reference frame? 
For a hemispherical tank you should need to evaluate at least a double integral since the radius of the "disks" of molasses as they're called in the linked source varies with height for a hemisphere.

Comment: @klunkean, for the reference frame, I used it in a way to write the radius in terms of the height.  It is the same method used by BlackPenRedPen in their video: [link](https://youtu.be/exGqWWAkhto).  I don't think I need to use a double integral though, because I have never had to use them for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your work is correct and the given solution is wrong.  Using the formula for the volume of a spherical cap, the volume of the molasses is $40\pi/3=41.9.$  That makes the weight of the molassis $4190$ pounds.  It all gets moved at least $2$ feet, so that's at least $8380$ ft.lbs.  The given answer is way below that.  Yours seems about right.